# Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type

Tags: swift

I created two classes `Content` and `Bucket`.  `Bucket` contains an array of `Content` objects and exposes that via a public property.  However, when I do so, I receive the error:

> Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type

[image]

Any thoughts on why this is raising an error?

Comment: It'd be nice to see a way to only expose a basic class to the public, like `public(Array<NSObject>) let contents: Array<Content>`

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You have to declare the access level of the `Content` class public as well.

```
public class Content {
   // some code
}
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html):

> A public variable cannot be defined as having an internal or private
>   type, because the type might not be available everywhere that the
>   public variable is used.

Classes are declared as `internal` by default, so you have to add the `public` keyword to make them public.

A similar rule exists for functions as well.

> A function cannot have a higher access level than its parameter types
>   and return type, because the function could be used in situations
>   where its constituent types are not available to the surrounding code.

Comment: Great answer. I also found that the error would not go away until Xcode (9.2) was restarted.

Comment: It is declared public but still not working for me :(

Answer (score 15):

`Content` must be declared as public too:

```
public class Content {
  …
}
```

Depending on your use-case you might declare `Bucket` as internal, too. Just omit the `public` keyword in this case.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was a namespace problem.

I had declared an enum called `Data` and that was mucking with the Swift `Data` class, especially an `imageData: Data` property within a Core Data model.