# Property cannot be declared open because its type uses an internal type (Typealias)

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, access-control, type-alias

I have seen this trick to implement a platform-agnostic interface to (say) the image classes UIImage/NSImage:

```
#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    typealias Image = UIImage

#elseif os(macOS)
    import Cocoa
    typealias Image = NSImage

#endif
```

Now I am trying to adopt it in a framework. Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public final class MyClass {

    public var image: Image // < Compiler Error (see below)

    init?(imageURL: URL) {
        guard let image = Image(contentsOf: imageFileURL) else {
        return nil
        }
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Property cannot be declared open because its type uses an internal type

Is the "internal type" refering to NSImage? **How do I get around this?**

---

**Note:** I don't think this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31792733/433373): I am using a **typealias**, it is not evident **what** declaration I sould mark as "public".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case (when used within a framework target), making the `typealias` public will not solve the issue. You need to use the platform condition check also when declaring the image property, as follows:

```
#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    typealias Image = UIImage
#elseif os(macOS)
    import Cocoa
    typealias Image = NSImage
#endif

public final class MyClass {

    #if os(iOS)
        public var image: UIImage
    #elseif os(macOS)
        public var image: NSImage
    #endif

    init?(imageURL: URL) {
        guard let image = Image(contentsOf: imageFileURL) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

The same applies for any public methods that use this type, whether it is a parameter or the return type of a function.

*Offtopic: Make sure to initialize this class on a background queue/thread to avoid blocking the main thread and freezing the UI while the image is being downloaded.*

Comment: Thank you. It kinda sucks that I have to thake the `#if os(...` everywhere, but I see the point somwhow.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Making typealias public compiles fine on my side, not sure why it wouldn't be the case on yours...

Comment: @nyg, have you tried it in a framework? I have a framework that does this exact thing, and I need to check for the OS when declaring public properties or public methods that need that type. Exposing the typealias is not enough for a framework, not sure why.

Comment: @EnekoAlonso Re: The background loading, these are always local file URLs. I like it this way more than using the (now) discouraged path/string APIs.